# Survey Gopher was incorrectly three-dimensionalized

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-developer-survey

The new Survey Gopher has a nice perspective survey pad, with an ugly unmodified SO logo in it.
The logo needs to have matching perspective.

[image: \ ≠ |]

Comment: The ads are in 3-D?  Where are my glasses?

Comment: @The: Only the clipboard is.

Comment: That parallel line doesn't look very freehand. :o It doesn't match the rest of the lines!

Comment: @animuson: It was freehand (although zoomed in a little)

Comment: @Wont: I'm picky about my graphics, and this is "off" enough that I don't want to see it in 35% of my browser tabs for the next three weeks.

Comment: The back of the clipboard is actually a mirror and is reflecting the logo in the corner.

Comment: @tvanfosson: That would still need different perspective

Comment: @SLaks - you're just looking at it from the wrong angle. :-)